# The wait operation time out , EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I use EF Code First on sql 2012 and I want to run following code on seed method but application throw *The wait operation time out exception*.

```
SqlCommand fileTableCommand2 = new SqlCommand(
                string.Format(@"
                Declare @Temp   nVarchar(500)
                Select  @Temp   = FileTableRootPath() + '{0}-Directory'
                If  (@Temp  Is Null)
                Begin
                    Alter Database {0}
                        Set FileStream  (NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = Full, Directory_Name = '{0}-Directory')
                End",
                            builder.InitialCatalog),
                            new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString));

            fileTableCommand2.Connection.Open();
            fileTableCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            fileTableCommand2.Connection.Close();
```

command works successfully when I try to execute in sql server, but throwing exception with above code.

Comment: ..how long does the proc take to run when you run it on the server? Longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: hi , no it run immediatly (1 second)

Comment: Okay. You've mentioned EF Code First - but all I see is vanilla ADO.NET. I am wondering whether you have a transaction open in EF that is causing your ADO.NET to time out...

Comment: Yes , i think , you are true , but how can i solve it?

Comment: Don't mix the two - call the proc from EF instead.

Comment: Thank you, but with store procedure not work too